# How can I access(and convert) 'date' to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Here is MongoDB scheme.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("222222"),
    "active" : false,
    "amount" : "15%",
    "description" : "15% discount",
    "name" : "20200628-test",
    "policies" : {
        "apply" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "expiryDate",
                "params" : {
                    "date" : ISODate("2020-07-06T14:59:59.999Z")
                }
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "isApplyCategoryExist"
            }
        ],
        "discount" : [],
        "conflict" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "exclusive"
            }
        ],
        "grant" : []
    },
    "target" : {
        "sku" : "",
        "products_ids" : [],
        "category_ids" : [ 
            ObjectId("11111111")
        ]
    },
    "title" : "15% coupon"
}
```

I want to access date.
For example,  "policies.apply.params.date"...

I don't know how to access 'date' to Javascript.
Please let me know...

Answer (score 0):

`apply` is an array, so you have to give it index which you want to get.

```js
var num = 0; // pick up an array number you want
var date = policies.apply[num].params.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your policies.apply is an array so if you want to access "2020-07-06T14:59:59.999Z", you should do this:

```
policies.apply[0].params.date
```

But the "policies.apply[1]" doesn't have params (params.date also) so you can write a function to get date like this:

```
function get_apply_date(index) {
    if(policies.apply[index].params && policies.apply[index].params.date)
        return policies.apply[index].params.date;
    return undefined; // or null
}
```